# What does "downshear" mean?

Tags: terminology, atmospheric-science, weather, vortex, meteorology

I occasionally read descriptions such as ["downshear of the vortex"](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=downshear+of+the+vortex) in meteorological publications.

What does this mean?

Comment: Have you done a Google search for this?

Comment: Yes, they came up quite fruitless - feel free to point me in the right direction though.

Answer (score 1):

In meteorology, the shear vector is typically calculated as the vector difference of the wind aloft minus the wind below (often using layer averages), much of which is further detailed [here](http://www.weather.gov/media/lmk/soo/Hodographs_Wind-Shear.pdf).

The reason this usage is heavy in meteorology stems from the fact that the vortices being talked about are often at the storm scale; features like tornadoes, mesocyclones, and supercells.  A very important mechanism in the development of these rotations is the generation of streamwise vorticity due by this vertical variation, or shear, of the environmental wind, as discussed in [Davies-Jones 1984](http://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/1520-0469(1984)041%3C2991%3ASVTOOU%3E2.0.CO%3B2).

Upshear thereby means occurring against this shear vector.  Upshear and downshear can often be used in describing the development of the cold pool and  updrafts, and relates to how storms (and thus their vortices) evolve.  [This page](http://www.geosci.sfsu.edu/geosciences/classes/m835/shear/print.htm) offers very quality descriptions of how storms may interact with the shear vector.

Answer (score 0):

"Downshear of the vortex"? 
And your link is just a google search for these words.
-But as Vortex doesn't have too much shear stresses, 
[image]

it must mean this [bottom flow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDw_7UIGCOo&feature=youtu.be&t=150) which connects/feeds the low pressure vortex center with fluid.

Please note that it doesn't make any difference if the fluid is going away from the bottom or from the top of the vortex. (Same video at 11:00)
[image]

I have coloured quite complete videos available here, in this [play list](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48zDbyy22x4&list=PLgUc9kJnDMMExJivT2dWh9dAjdYYUgOFE&index=11)
Start at 5:00 in this video,,

Comment: To clarify: In the first two images, the dye is at the surface, in the second two it it near (but not at) the bottom. No matter if the water is removed from the bottom (a drain) or the top (the suction pipe), the water near the bottom is sacrificed to the outlet, allowing the other water to flow with very low friction.